# Recursive positive digits sum program

Tags: c, recursion, function-definition

I'm facing an issue, the program almost works correctly except it gives +1 in output result. For example num input is 123 = 1+2+3=6, instead it gives 7 as output.

I can simply fix this problem by adding -1 in the `printf` statement, but I want to know why this is happening.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int Sumdigits(int num);

int Sumdigits(int num){
    if(num<1){
        return 1;
    }
    else return (num%10+Sumdigits(num/10));
}

int main(){
    int num;
    printf("Enter Number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    printf("%d",Sumdigits(num));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Sumdigits( 0 )` will return `1` instead of `0`, which does not make sense. To fix this, change

```
if(num<1){
    return 1;
}
```

to:

```
if(num<1){
    return 0;
}
```

It is also worth noting that your code will not work with negative numbers. Therefore, you may want to change the function `Sumdigits` to the following:

```
int Sumdigits( int num )
{
    if( num == 0 )
        return 0;

    if ( num < 0 )
        num = -num;

    return num % 10 + Sumdigits(num/10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding 1 in this if statement

```
if(num<1){
    return 1;
```

The function should be declared and defined like

```
unsigned int Sumdigits( unsigned int num )
{
    return num == 0 ? 0 : num % 10 + Sumdigits( num / 10 );
}
```

If the user is allowed to deal with negative integer values then the function can be defined the following way

```
unsigned int Sumdigits( int num )
{
    unsigned int digit = num < 0 ? -( num % 10 ) : num % 10;

    return num == 0 ? 0 : digit + Sumdigits( num / 10 );
}
```

Comment: I'd be hesitant to ever say to a novice programmer, that they *should* use `?:` operator.

Comment: @hyde There is no any problem. It is an operator and beginners learn operators.

Comment: Yeah, but this is recursion. Even in (or maybe, especially in) production code it would be good idea to make the base case explicit, separate return, instead of "hiding" it in ternary operator. This is subjective of course, YMMV.

Comment: @hyde There  code is enough clear.

Answer (score 0):

`if (num < 1)` is only handled when the digit is zero, but then you return `1`, instead, so adding one to the result.  This happens always, as this is the cut'n go back case that is executed always at the deepest recursion level.

It should read:

```
    if (num < 1)
        return 0;
```

(if you check, the only possibility for a valid number is to be zero, as it is an integer going down from a large number until you have no more digits, when you exhaust the number, it is actually zero, so it can be more readably written:

```
    if (num == 0)
        return 0;
```

meaning if we are at the end, then just add zero.